# Indoor urination issues with puppy chihuahua

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, urination

How to stop my chihuahua puppy from peeing inside although he pees outside every time he goes outside?

He is a 10 month old chihuahua and he pees every time we take him out. Then, after he gets back inside and play awhile, he will stop and pee whenever he gets the urge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppy Crate Training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16110/puppy-crate-training)